# sigsev error on malloc that's driving me nuts

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault, malloc

This bit of C code is giving segmentation error in gdb

```
if ((seq_entry_action=malloc((seq_subphases)*sizeof(int*)))==NULL){
    printf("Cannot allocate memory for seq_entry_action\n");
}
```

where:

```
int **seq_entry_action=NULL;
unsigned int seq_subphases=0;
```

At the time of executing, and If I add a breakpoint in gdb just before this snippet of code (it's just another printf() statement) , the values are

```
(gdb) p seq_subphases
$3 = 88
(gdb) p seq_entry_action
$4 = (int **) 0x0
```

then I press next and it segfaults at malloc

I really don't get it.....

Comment: That's usually because you've corrupted your heap. Which means the error could be just about anywhere in your code. Try `valgrind`.

Comment: Ran that bit of code under centos 6.2 and gcc version 4.4.6 and it compiled and ran fine which means somewhere you corrupted your heap.

Comment: +1 for being the first one today on SO who doesn't cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: Can you run your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: it was like that indeed... an earlier malloc of wrongly computed sizeof() was the reason this malloc failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was like that indeed... an earlier malloc of wrongly computed sizeof() was the reason this malloc failed.